# Is it still disjunction?

Tags: logic

In one of my previous question , I came across the idea $x \leq y$ is a disjunction of two mathematical statements - $x < y$ and $x = y$.

But according to the truth table for disjunction , It's also true in the condition when both the statements are true , but in case $x \leq y$ , both $x \leq y$ and $x = y$ cannot be simultaneously be true because of law of trichotomy .

So will it still be disjunction if an entire condition is invalidated , because then logically the statement will be true only in 2 conditions and false is 1 condition - consideration for the 4th condition (where both the statements are true) is invalid and so it's not even in the truth table ? Is it still Disjunction ?

Comment: How does the law of trichotomy invalidate the possibility that $x\leq y$ and $x=y$ simultaneously? Or do you mean to say $x<y$ and $x=y$?

Comment: @Clayton because according to law of trichotomy for any real numbers x and y only one of the 3 conditions can hold at the same time - either x<y or x>y or x=y and as only of the 3 conditions can hold together so 2 conditions can't be true at the same time.

Comment: So you mean to say $x<y$ and $x=y$ cannot hold simultaneously? I assure you that $x\leq y$ and $x=y$ can hold simultaneously... Simply $2\leq 2$ and $2=2$ as a trivial example. However, $2\not<2$.

Comment: @Clayton - By your example , In 2<=2 , 2<2 is not true whereas 2=2 is true which again proves my statement that either of the 3 statements can hold true and that's just according to Law of trichotomy

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi Clayton's pointing out a typo in what you wrote - when you say "both $x\le y$ and $x=y$ cannot be simultaneously true," the "$\le$" should be a "$<$."

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We say that such statements as "if $ x \lt y \land x= y$ then $x \le y$" are "vacuously true": as the "if" clause can never be satisfied, the statement overall is always true. More true statements are "if $ x \lt y \land x= y$ then $1=0 $" or "if $2=1$ then $1=0$".

We could instead use an "xor" gate, which returns true iff exactly one of the two inputs is true, but we may as well use disjunction; the conditions are equivalent.

Comment: A simpler example of this logic could be the statement "if $1=0$ then $2=1$" wich is (vacuously) true. Note that the statement "if $1=0$ then $1=1$" is also true.

Comment: Thanks , because I think XOR would be a better answer.

Comment: @MaxFt I've replaced the examples with simpler ones like yours.